# What gc_collect_cycles function is useful for?

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection

Can someone please explain under what circumstances [gc_collect_cycles](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) function can be useful? Should it be called before a substantial memory utilization is about to take place?

Comment: Does this help? http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php

Comment: It seems like gc_collect_cycles is only really useful for when the GC is *disabled*.

Answer (score 31):

PHP has "Garbage Collector" enabled by default. It is used to free memory used by "garbage".
`gc_collect_cycles()` forces collection of any existing garbage cycles. It returns number of collected (freed) cycles (objects, variable values ...). Enabled Garbage Collector calls this function internally from time to time to free resources. In most cases PHP script lives very short time. In this case all garbage will be destroyed in the end of work without any garbage collection.

Sometimes it's needed to manage GC manually:

1. `gc_disable()` can speed up some long operations, but also results in some memory overheads.
2. `gc_collect_cycles()` could be used to specify the right moments of GC.

Another one reason to use `gc_collect_cycles()` - debugging. Assume, you want to know what is the memory consumption of some block of code with `memory_get_usage()`. You need to disable GC first, elsewhere you'll get wrong results. After that you want to separate the time consumed by GC and by your application. So call `gc_collect_cycles()` and measure timings/memory before and after.

**Little example:**

```
class A {
  public $ref;
  public $name;

  public function __construct($name) {
    $this->name = $name;
    echo($this->name.'->__construct();'.PHP_EOL);
  }

  public function __destruct() {
    echo($this->name.'->__destruct();'.PHP_EOL);
  }
}

gc_disable();

$a1 = new A('$a1');
$a2 = new A('$a2');

$a1->ref = $a2;
$a2->ref = $a1;

$b = new A('$b');
$b->ref = $a1;

echo('$a1 = $a2 = $b = NULL;'.PHP_EOL);
$a1 = $a2 = $b = NULL;
echo('gc_collect_cycles();'.PHP_EOL);
echo('// removed cycles: '.gc_collect_cycles().PHP_EOL);
echo('exit();'.PHP_EOL);
```

Will output:

```
$a1->__construct();
$a2->__construct();
$b->__construct();
$a1 = $a2 => $b = NULL;
$b->__destruct();
gc_collect_cycles();
$a2->__destruct();
$a1->__destruct();
// removed cycles: 4
```

*This means that only `$b` was destroyed when it was asked. Other `$a1` and `$a2` has cyclic references, and it's `name` properties also consume memory. Two objects + two strings = 4 (removed by `gc_collect_cycles()`)*.

Comment: Thank you @clover!
I was always wondering how we can free up some resources. This is clever and easy!

Comment: PHP works internally by having both reference counting and true garbage collection (that's able to collect loops, too). However, the garbage collection is really expensive compared to reference counting and reference counting can release all memory except loops, so only reference counting is typically used. You can use `gc_collect_cycles()` to trigger garbage collection immediately if you have known reference loops and want to release the memory. Without explicit call, it will be called only if PHP process is getting close to "out of memory" status, or at the end of request in case of mod_php.